# Restart CoreAudio... to fix Safari problems?! Why?

Tags: safari, audio, launchd, quicktime, development

On my M1 Macbook Pro (2020) running Big Sur 11.3.1, I've found that I need to restart CoreAudio to solve seemingly unrelated problems. For example:

1. Safari will stop rendering content... Safari is still working, I can go to other tabs, but it will just stop rendering content. I found if I kill and restart CoreAudio, the page snaps into existence.
2. Quicktime won't launch... it just keeps bouncing in the dock. I kill and restart CoreAudio and then it starts right up.
3. Zoom is unresponsive... restart CoreAudio and we're good.

If I'm experiencing problems in one of these apps, the problem extends to all of them. So if I notice that Safari is wonky, I'll try to launch Quicktime and it won't launch either. These apps must all be reliant on the same CoreAudio thing.

I discovered this fix by trial and error. Every once in awhile my audio would get crackly and restarting CoreAudio fixed it... which makes sense. So, on a whim I tried this to fix the Safari situation and it worked.

So what the heck is going on here? How do I figure out what's corrupting CoreAudio? How do I fix it?

---

This is how I'm restarting CoreAudio, BTW. In Terminal:

`sudo launchctl stop com.apple.audio.coreaudiod && sudo launchctl start com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party audio apps or interfaces? I had an issue a while back where I got the same symptoms, fixed by toggling 44.1-48kHz [ which I imagine resets CoreAudio in the same way] Mine just 'went away' with no conclusive fix - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383136/usb-audio-oddity/383157#383157

Comment: @Tetsujin No, nothing like that installed. The only somewhat weird things I have installed (_that I can think of_) are BetterTouchTool and DisplayLink. Both are widely used. I'd like to think if either of those caused problems, I'd find it via a Google search... which I've done. Nothing comes up.